# Is it possible to show one column value only once but another column value multiple times when column value is the same

Tags: php, mysql

idk if it's possible, but I'm going to ask anyway.
I have a MYSQL database with a column called **encounter**, **mode** & **encounter_id**.

example: if the **encounter_id** value = 4, the **encounter** value = "Crota" (exists more than once) & the **mode** value is both "Normal" & "Master", is it possible to show "Crota" only once, but show both "Normal" & "Master" in an echo?

Query:

```
$ce = $database->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `raid_list` WHERE `raid_id` = 13 ORDER BY `encounter_id` ASC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

PHP:

```
<?php foreach($ce as $data) {
      echo '<div class="encounter">';
      echo '<p>' . $data['encounter'] . '</p>';
      echo '<p>(' . $data['mode'][0] . ')</p>';
      echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

If it's not possible, then that's okay. I just want to know if it's possible or not.

EDIT: Here's the database image
[image: Database Image]

Comment: sure it is possible a little bit flow-control and you get your wanted result

Comment: How can the mode be _both_ Normal and Master? Do you mean that it could be either value, or does that column contain multiple values? Perhaps you could edit the question to show some sample data, and your desired output.

Comment: @droopsnoot I added the database image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restructure the array into a format which can be iterated easily. I think you are looking for something like this.

```php
<?php
$results = array_reduce($ce, function($carry, $current) {
  $modes = $carry[$current['encounter']]['modes'] ?? [];
  array_push($modes, $current['mode']);
  $carry[$current['encounter']] = ['modes' => array_unique($modes)];
  return $carry;
});

foreach($results as $encounter => $encounterData) {
  echo '<div class="encounter">';
  echo '<p>' . $encounter . '</p>';
  echo '<p>(' . implode(', ', $encounterData['modes']) . ')</p>';
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
```